# How to maintain the state of the activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to save the state of the activity in android.Basic scenario is there is 2 activities A and B.Activity A contains 2 edittext fields.User enters some value into it and moves to activity B via intent.When user comes back to Activity A (by intent i have provided a back button) I need to display those values in the 2 edittext fields that the user had entered (i.e maintain the state of activity A).Also i do not want to use shared preferences or make those fields as static.
I have used the following code but it does not help:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manual_entry);
            edittext1=(Edittext)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    }

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          savedInstanceState.putString("cardvalue_saved_inst", value_card_manuallyentered);
    }




@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      value_savedinstance = savedInstanceState.getString("cardvalue_saved_inst");
      Log.e("value_savedinstance",""+value_savedinstance);
      edittext1.setText(value_savedinstance);
    }
```

Comment: use shared preferences to store and gt values

Comment: so do you see value_savedinstance in log?

Comment: Raghunandan ,Can i achieve it without using sharedpreferences i think it should be possible with savedinstanceState but the above does not work for me.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic , No.

Comment: Check if your activity is being recreated, ensure 'onCreate()' is not being called when you return to the activity.

Comment: try by storing the manually entered value in `private static String value_card_manuallyentered;` of `Activity A` .let me know if it works,i will make it as answer.

Comment: Please post the code that shows how `ActivityA` launches `ActivityB` and how `ActivityB` comes back to `ActivityA`.

Answer (score 0):

In `ActivityA`, if you launch `ActivityB` and don't call `finish()` on yourself, when `ActivityB` finishes (when user presses BACK button or otherwise), `ActivityA` will be shown in the same state that it was in. This is just standard Android behaviour and you don't need to do anything special.

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is **not called** if a paused activity gets resumed (which is the usual case where `ActivityA` launches `ActivityB` and `ActivityB` then finishes).

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is **only called** if Android killed your activity (during orientation change for example) or killed your process. In that case, when the user returns to your activity, Android will create a new instance of the activity and then call `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to simply call finish() in Activity B and it worked.